# "Извините за мой французский" - откуда выражение?

Tags: этикет, фразеология

После использования кем-либо неприличных в данном обществе слов и выражений, доводилось слышать от произнёсшего их, - "Извините, за мой французский". Откуда появилось данное выражение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В конце XVIII-XIX века русские дворяне учились французскому у франкоязычных гувернёров, которые обучали их высокому языку и, конечно, не учили французским ругательствам. Именно поэтому следом за руганью шло «простите мой французский», поскольку фраза могла быть неправильно построенной или вообще с не совсем французскими словами — в середине чистой французской речи.  Является дословным переводом английского выражения «pardon my French» (вариант: excuse my French), собственно, то же самое и обозначающего. В английском употреблялась изначально только для нефранцузских слов, теперь тоже после грубых слов и выражений. Подробнее здесь: http://lurkmore.to/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: Ссылка у Вас, Людмила, изумительная!!! Вы это всерьез или шутите)

Comment: Источник... гм... неавторитетный, а ссылка вполне себе нормальная. )))
Другое дело, что сама версия может быть раскритикована... Идея дворянского происхождения плохо стыкуется с предположением о кальке с английского.

Comment: Юмор, конечно, но, я думаю, здесь тоже у всех с юмором нормально, если такой вопрос задают. И так понятно, что ситуация похожая:смесь французского с нижегородским и желание блеснуть образованностью. Особой истории нет, а похожих ситуаций множество. Кто ж знает, когда и кто сказал первый эту фразу? А анекдотов на эту тему ещё больше.

Comment: Не похоже, что дворяне извинялись за свой французский, после русских выражений. Косвенно об этом говорит хотя бы то, что фраза *извиняюсь за мой французский* частотнее, а "извиняюсь" дворяне не говорили.

Comment: Марк Из, ну что Вы... Это же шутка...Пародия на Википедию. Автор этого сайта хочет сказать,что фраза имеет источником любую ситуацию, когда человек хочет блеснуть образованностью (как блестяще образованный дворянин),говорит на якобы французском, не зная его, потому и извиняется за свою смесь "французского с нижегородским". Искать реальную историю фразы не стоит, её нет,это типично.

Comment: Почему же? Вы же историю и привели в ответе. Калька с английского выражения. Английские фразеологизмы могли попасть через литературу или кино. В классической литературе такой контекст маловероятен, следовательно скорей всего через переводы кинофильмов. 

Сайт, кстати, по большей вполне себе нормальный и факты ставит превыше  "лулзов", хотя за последнюю инстанцию его тоже принимать не стоит.

Comment: И вряд ли мы вспомним фильм, после которого фраза  "пошла в народ".Может, это и не фильм. Это приём иронии, просто фраза, расхожая ситуация, никак не фразеологизм. А "как бы фразеологизмом" стала из-за повторяемости, с юмором стали говорить, иронизируя над употреблением грубых выражений, когда от тебя ждут французской изысканности.Это как бы народный юмор.